# How to create OpenSolaris self bundle volume on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, opensolaris

I'm using OpenSolaris 2008.11 on EC2.
I want to create self bundle .
in ubuntu

```
sudo ec2-bundle-vol -d /mnt -k $EC2_PRIVATE_KEY  -c $EC2_CERT  --fstab /etc/fstab --user $AWS_ACCUNT_ID  -r i386
```

but OpenSolaris does not have /etc/fstab

Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on rebundling OpenSolaris AMIs here: http://www.sun.com/third-party/global/amazon/Sun_AmazonEC2_GettingStartedGuide.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSolaris, `/etc/fstab` has been replaced by `/etc/vfstab`.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris has no fstab, its called vfstab: [Man vfstab](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/vfstab.4.html)